# how to add multiple test cases in a test suite inside jenkinsfile for jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, automated-tests, squish

I have a stage on jenkins which has to execute squish tests. Inside the jenkins file I have:

```
step([$class: 'SquishBuilder',
               squishConfig: 'Default',
               testSuite: env.WORKSPACE +"/test_suites/suite_sample_module2"])
```

I have actually various tests inside test_suites was trying to add to the stage as:

```
step([$class: 'SquishBuilder',
               squishConfig: 'Default',
               testSuite: '''env.WORKSPACE + "/test_suites/suite_sample_module2" env.WORKSPACE + "/test_suites/suite_sample_module2"'''])
```

But it's not reading it as separate suites so, suggest how to add multiple test cases against test_suites fields.

Answer (score 1):

The testSuite entries must be separated by a newline character. If unsure, consider using the "Pipeline Syntax" > "Sample Step" > "step: General Build Step" and "Build Step" > "Squish" (requires the dedicated Squish plug-in for Jenkins, not the one that supports Hudson *and* Jenkins).